# Animate creating of cgrect on drawRect not working

Tags: ios, uiview, drawrect

I have a scene of storyboard with a UIVIewcontroller. Inside this scene i have a UIImageview that contains the background image, an UIButton, and an UIView.

This UIView have a overrided drawRect method with:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{

    CGFloat height = self.bounds.size.height-15; // - 15 for text space

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextClearRect(context, rect);

    UIColor *barColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:226.0/255.0 green:178.0/255.0 blue:39.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];

    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, barColor.CGColor);
    CGFloat barWidth = 37.5;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{
        int count = 0;
        NSArray *values = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@1, @0.5, @0.2, @0.7, nil];
        for (NSNumber *num in values) {

            CGFloat x = count * (barWidth + 18);
            CGFloat startY = (height - ([num floatValue] * height));
            CGRect barRect = CGRectMake(x, startY+15, barWidth, [num floatValue] * height);
            CGContextAddRect(context, barRect);
            // save context state first
            CGContextSaveGState(context);
            [self drawWords:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%%",num] AtPoint:CGPointMake(x + (barWidth/2)-10 , startY) color:[UIColor whiteColor]];
            count++;
            // restore context state first
            CGContextRestoreGState(context);

        }
    }];
    CGContextFillPath(context);
}
```

I've tried animate the grow up of bars but not work..my question is: how can i make this work?

Regards

----UPDATED WITH NEW CODE BUT NOT WORKING ALREADY

---CODE OF GRAPHVIEW

```
- (void) initHelper {
    height=0;
    graphBars = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
     [self performSelector:@selector(animateBars) withObject:NULL afterDelay:0.5];
}

- (void) animateBars
{
    for (GraphBar *bar in graphBars)
    {
        bar.bottom+=bar.height;
    }

    CGFloat barWidth=37.5;
    CGFloat rat = self.frame.size.height*0.95;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 animations:^{

        NSUInteger _index = 0;
        for (GraphBar *bar in graphBars)
        {
            bar.frame = CGRectMake(_index*(barWidth+18),  self.frame.size.height-roundf(bar.barValue*rat), barWidth, roundf(bar.barValue*rat));

            _index++;
        }
    }];
}

- (void) layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];

    CGFloat barWidth=37.5;
    CGFloat rat = self.frame.size.height*0.01;

    NSUInteger _index = 0;
    for (GraphBar *bar in graphBars)
    {
        bar.frame = CGRectMake(_index*(barWidth+18),  self.frame.size.height-roundf(bar.barValue*rat), barWidth, roundf(bar.barValue*rat));

        _index++;

    }
```

---CODE OF BAR VIEW

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{

    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextClearRect(context, rect);

    UIColor *barColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:226.0/255.0 green:178.0/255.0 blue:39.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];

    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, barColor.CGColor);

    CGContextAddRect(context, rect);

    CGContextFillPath(context);
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of simply using the `+animateWithDuration:animations:` convenience method, use the more detailed `+animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:` method which allows you to pass the `UIViewAnimationOptionAllowAnimatedContent` option. Then change the height of your view in the `animations` block to let the view and bars height grow during the animation.

This option is specially here to tell CoreAnimation to redraw your content during the animation (calling `drawRect:` at each step of the animation). Without it, the animation is done on a snapshot image.

---

*From the [UIView class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIViewAnimationOptions) documentation:*

> `UIViewAnimationOptionAllowAnimatedContent`
>
> Animate the views by changing the property values dynamically and redrawing the view. If this key is not present, the views are animated using a snapshot image.

---

Alternatively, you could instead use one `UIView` for each of your bar, and use `+animateWithDuration:animations:` to animate those bars frame, instead of drawing them using CoreGraphics (as `UIView` animation methods are meant for animating properties of the view (`frame`, `alpha`, …) and its `subviews`, not primarily to animate the drawing done with `CoreGraphics`)

Comment: im tried to do what you say but not working..i edited my question with new code

Comment: Of course it does not work. Why are you putting the `animateWithDuration:…` method call… in the `drawRect:` method? This does not make sense at all! You should call it outside instead, and CoreAnimation will make sure to animate the change in view height… and that the view is drawn at each frame as you specified the aforementioned option. `drawRect:` is only in charge of drawing **one** frame/state.

Comment: I create the function -(void)anim with the code that are in question updated and then call this function in viewDidLoad of viewController but i cant view the animation, only the change of height 0 to max in an instant change. why?

Comment: I don't get it : what is your `height` variable in your latest code update? A local variable that is then totally ignored and lost ?! (Or an instance variable used in your `drawRect` code later? In that latest case, that's now how it works as explained before. That is the change of the `UIView`'s `frame` that will be animated, not affectation of any `height` arbitrary variable! (You should **really** read the Programming Guide related to CoreAnimation and animatable properties!)

Comment: Thank you for your help i've made all the changes but still not working at time..I make each bar as an independent simple view (one rectangle) and after i make an graphView with all bar views as subviews..But the bars not grow up...the updated code are in question update

Comment: But this "applies to transitions only" (quote from header file).